# Android Listview Select Item

Tags: android, android-listview

I have minimum Ten item food into Listview.

I want select one or more item food .

And pressed Order button.

Then show me total price for select item food.

How possible please tell me?

#### MenuListItem:

```
package com.example.project_hotel_management;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MenuListItem extends Activity{

    ListView lv;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menuitemlist_layout);

    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    adapter=new MyAdapter(this , getListItem());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "d", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    }

    public ArrayList<ListItem> getListItem() {
        ArrayList<ListItem> alllist=new ArrayList<ListItem>();

        ListItem l1=new ListItem("beef_burguer", 1, R.drawable.beef_burguer);
        ListItem l2=new ListItem("bacon_cheese_burger", 2, R.drawable.bacon_cheese_burger);
        ListItem l3=new ListItem("frings", 3, R.drawable.frings);
        ListItem l4=new ListItem("burger_kingse", 4, R.drawable.burger_kingse);
        ListItem l5=new ListItem("mint_oreo", 5, R.drawable.mint_oreo);
        ListItem l6=new ListItem("sourdough_bread", 6, R.drawable.sourdough_bread);
        ListItem l7=new ListItem("sandwich", 7, R.drawable.sandwich);
        ListItem l8=new ListItem("sandwich_loaded", 8, R.drawable.sandwich_loaded);
        ListItem l9=new ListItem("mustard", 9, R.drawable.mustard);
        ListItem l10=new ListItem("cheese_burger", 10, R.drawable.cheese_burger);

        alllist.add(l1);
        alllist.add(l2);
        alllist.add(l3);
        alllist.add(l4);
        alllist.add(l5);
        alllist.add(l6);
        alllist.add(l7);
        alllist.add(l8);
        alllist.add(l9);
        alllist.add(l10);



        return alllist;
    }

    public void order(View v) {

        String result="";
        List<Integer> resultList=adapter.getCheckedItemPosition();
        for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
            result+=String.valueOf(resultList.get(i))+"\n";
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

#### MyAdapter:

```
package com.example.project_hotel_management;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData.Item;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem>{

    Activity context;
    ArrayList<ListItem> listItem;

    HashMap<Integer, Boolean> myChecked=new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

    public MyAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<ListItem> listItem) {
        super(context, R.layout.adapter_layout, listItem);
         this.context=context;
         this.listItem=listItem;

       for (int i = 0; i < listItem.size(); i++) {
        myChecked.put(i, false);
    }

    }


    public void toggleChecked(int position) {
        if(myChecked.get(position)){
            myChecked.put(position, false);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            myChecked.put(position, true);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public List<Integer> getCheckedItemPosition() {
        List<Integer> checkedItemPosition=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < myChecked.size(); i++) {
            checkedItemPosition.add(i);
        }
        return checkedItemPosition;
    }

//  public List<Integer> getCheckedItem() {
//      List<Integer> checkedItem=new ArrayList<Integer>();
//      
//      for (int i = 0; i < myChecked.size(); i++) {
//          checkedItem.add();
//      }
//      return checkedItem;
//  }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view=convertView;

            LayoutInflater inflat=context.getLayoutInflater();
            view=inflat.inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, null, false);
            TextView txtName=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            TextView txtPrice=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
            ImageView image=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            ListItem l=listItem.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(listItem.get(position)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG
             ).show();

            txtName.setText(l.getName());
            txtPrice.setText(String.valueOf(l.getPrice()));
            image.setImageResource(l.getImage());

            CheckBox chekboxs=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            Boolean chekBox=myChecked.get(position);

            if(chekBox!=null){
                chekboxs.setChecked(chekBox);
            }


        return view;
    }
}
```

#### ListItem:

```
package com.example.project_hotel_management;

public class ListItem {

    String name;
    Integer price;
    Integer image;



    public ListItem(String name, Integer price, Integer image) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public Integer getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(Integer image) {
        image = image;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ListItem [name=" + name + ", price=" + price + ", Image="
                + image + "]";
    }
}
```

I use this but it's not working:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ListItem ls=getListItem().get(position);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(ls.getPrice()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}


});
```

Comment: http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-multiple-selection-listview.html

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"` on your listview. You can also implement a selector to define how the selected item will be highlighted. An example of a selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

Once one or more items in the `ListView` are selected, you can get the selected items by:

```
int len = listView.getCount();
SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
if (checked.get(i)) {
String item = cont_list.get(i);
/* calculate the price  */
}
```

Comment: I editted the question to also show how to do calculations based on the selected items.

Comment: I can not This code please help me ... i am beginner of android

Comment: i use this but not work  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
    long arg3) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   ListItem ls=getListItem().get(position);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(ls.getPrice()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   
   
  }
 
 
 });

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom listview to add checkboxes to each item in your listview. ANd on button click event you can traverse your list to identify which items have been selected and calculate the total amount.

Comment: i use this but it is not response                                                               lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
    long arg3) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "d", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   
  }
 
 
 });