# Android Listview Select Item Not Work Response

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a problem.My listview is not selected any item.What I do please tell me.
may Main code is:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877486/android-listview-select-item)

I use this code but it is not work.

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String ls= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(ls) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        }


    });
```

Comment: NO bro.. I is not Error

Comment: All listview show image ,text. But did not work Every Selected item

Comment: Try System.out.println(ls); in onItemClick and check from LogCat whether this is called or not

Comment: @user3467178 add this `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the root element in `adapter_layout.xml`. But after clicking it should crash. that is different issue

Comment: Please see my Code.Have any problem myAdapter class or another.Why is not work select Item

Comment: @user3467178 try the suggestion in my previous comment.

Comment: @user3467178 i am guessing that  imageview takes focus when you click on listitem. Also `String ls= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();` is wrong that is not the what `getItemAtPosition(position)` returns. also its better you post the code here. difficult look at the link always

Comment: @user3467178 what happens now??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the root element in `adapter_layout.xml`. I am guessing `ImageView` takes focus when you click on list item.

Also in `onItemClick`. Change to

```
ListItem item = (ListItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
String ls = item.getName();
```

coz you populate you list using `ArrayList` of `ListItem` which is a class with getter and setter's.

Comment: i use adapter layout  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" When you click layout then i will be checked autometically but Did not work Chekboxk. Chekbox has another coding??

Comment: post a new question. I will reply Tono.  Time to sleep